# What is the opposite of "avoidance"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am stuck looking for one word that captures the personal attribute of never avoiding issues; a concise way of saying that one deals with things "head-on" and in a timely manner.

I'd also like to phrase it a way that does not rely on a negation, such as "non-avoidant"

Update: I wasn't clear enough.  The word also needs to describe a positive attribute.  Thanks for suggesting "confrontational", which is an antonym, but it sounds negative to aim to be more confrontational.

The context for the word I'm looking for is: "Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to be [insert new word here]".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about "engaged"?

> Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to be engaged.

Comment: +1 except I've used up my daily quota so I can't. In OP's sentence it would be better as **I resolve to be more engaged**, or perhaps **...to engage more**.

Comment: Thanks @dillon.  I think engaged just pips it for me, though I still feel it doesn't exactly capture all what I want.  It will probably settle in with me though.  Actually I'm amazed it never came to me before!  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To me, the opposite of *avoidance* is *engagement*.

**EDIT**

A good word in your particular sentence might be *diligent*. It's not exactly the opposite of *avoidance* but I think fits better in your construction. Instead of avoiding problems, you want to be aware of them and work to solve them. *Perseverance*.

> Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to be diligent.

Answer (score 3):

If a phrasal verb will do: seek out.

Answer (score 3):

For this, I think the nonce coinage "embracement" might work.

Comment: That word occured to me as well, but I certainly wouldn't call it a "nonce coinage". It's just not that common. But I can't upvote you because I've used up my quota today. Anyway, it won't do because you can't *resolve to be more embracement*.

Answer (score 1):

One can say

- to *face up* to a problem
- *problems confronting*

**Edit**
Taking into account the precisions included in your edited question, a number of solutions (grouped by similarity) come to mind.

- Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to be more *combative/aggressive/pugnacious*!
- Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to *adopt a can do attitude*!
- Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to be more *anticipatory*!
- Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to be more *go-getting/feisty/spirited/determined*!

Answer (score 1):

The antonym to *avoid* is *confront*, hence a person that is non-avoidant is confronting or likes to be confronted with problems.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example sentence, I think "engaged" was the ideal choice.

For many other contexts, I add *intrepid* to the fray. It has a strong positive connotation.

Answer (score 0):

`What is the opposite of “avoidance”` is not your real question.

A way of saying that one deals with things "head-on" and in a timely manner is *proactive*.

"Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve [to be more **proactive**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20be%20more%20proactive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20more%20proactive%3B%2Cc0)."

> *proactive* : (of a person, policy, or action) creating or controlling a situation by causing something to happen rather than responding to it after it has happened. –Google

Although being proactive would require you to be *engaged*, being engaged does not necessarily mean that you are tackling the problem with a proactive approach, or "head-on". 'C' students might be *engaged*. 'A' students are *proactive*.

Answer (score 0):

> "Last year I avoided some problems, but this year I resolve to be
>   ***strong***".

ODO:

> **[strong](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/strong)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   **2.2** Not easily disturbed, upset, or affected.
>
> ‘The new Bollywood stars are role models for them, strong, independent
>   and bold.’
>   ‘They are strong and independent because they have to be,
>   not because they want to be.’